# Hanging mezuza for someone else - bracha?

Tags: halacha, blessing, mezuzah, shlichus-agency, home-house

If a visitor in someone else's home puts up a mezuza there, and the homeowner will not be home to hang it/make a bracha, does the visitor make the bracha when affixing it?  Does it matter whether or not the visitor was appointed a shaliach?

Comment: Seymore, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for bringing your question here! Please note that Mi Yodeya [offers](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1734) information as if from a crowd of your friends and not personal Rabbinic advice, so I have edited your question post accordingly. If this situation affects you practically, I hope you'll consult your rabbi regarding what you should do, possibly armed with useful information gleaned here. I hope you'll keep looking around the site for interesting material, perhaps starting with our 40 other [tag:mezuzah] questions.

Answer (score 3):

Yalkut Yosef YD 285 Seif 89 says the head of household can appoint a shaliach to affix all the mezuzot. However, the shaliach should make the bracha of "Al Keviat Mezuzah", because whenever a Misvah is done on behalf of someone else, you change it to that form.

I don't see any circumstance where the visitor won't be appointed a shaliach- is he going to sneak into the house and affix Mezuzot?

Comment: Ashkenazim wouldn't change the text of the blessing in that case.